# How do I compare data type with a variable in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to compare a variable with a type, something like this:

```
if "h" != int:
    
    print("its different")

else:
    print("its not")
```

And it shows that it's different, the problem is that the result is the same if I put a number instead of a character, I know that I could do the same using `if type("h") != type(1)` but I was wondering if it's possible to make the same using only types and not specific values like 1 or h

Comment: A string isn't a type, so it's never equal to a type, on the other hand, `type("h") == str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use isinstance

```
if not isinstance("h",int):
    print("its different")

else:
    print("its not")
```